# Customizing Search File Attachments result page

Tags: theming, search

I'm using [search_file_attachments](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_file_attachments) module for my search, And also `Search combine` module to show all the results in one page. In the search results page, I like to maintain a structure. I need to show the `node title` instead of `attached file name`, and redirect to `node url` instead of `attached file path` when a user click on a result. So implement the `template_preprocess_search_results()` in my module overwrite the results. I tried to figure out the array result using `devel`.

```
function template_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
  dpm($variables);
}
```

And this my Devel results:

[image]

I cannot see any node details here, I guess this module only searching files in the folders. I'm finding a way to get the node details related to this results. Hope you guys got my question, Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I ended up with some advanced search modules, Which made the search so much better. I used [Apache solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) and [Apache solr attachments](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_attachments) modules. This gave me ability to make my search results in a customized way via hooks. I use `hook_apachesolr_process_results()` to change my results.

First I add a extra field to the file type entities in the solr index, which contain the node title.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_apachesolr_index_document_build().
 */
function mymodule_apachesolr_index_document_build(ApacheSolrDocument $document, $entity, $entity_type, $env_id) {
    //dsm($entity_type);
    //if the type is file
    if($entity_type == 'file'){
        //add a field node title
        $title = code for getting the node tile of this file
        $document->addField('ts_field_node_title', $title);
    }
}
```

Now this extra field will be available in your search results. So you can directly use the title instead of file name.

```
/**
* Implements hook_apachesolr_process_results().
*/
function mymodule_apachesolr_process_results(&$arg) {

    for($i = 0, $l = count($arg); $i < $l; $i++) {
        //if entity type is file change the title
        if($arg[$i]['node']->entity_type != 'node'){
           $arg[$i]['title'] = $arg[$i]['fields']['ts_field_node_title'];
        }
    }

}
```

Peace! :)